# Difference between divergent series and series with no limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can a series have a limit and be divergent?  I'm confused about the difference between divergence and a series not having a limit.  A ck-12 calculus book stated they are different concepts.

Comment: The limit could be $\infty$ for example, in which case we still say it's divergent.

Comment: If you are reading this from a calculus book, make sure you are talking about the same objects having a limit. For example, a series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the sequence of partial sums $s_k = \sum_{n = 1}^k a_n$ has a limit as $k$ approaches $\infty$. This is not the same as determining if the sequence $a_n$ has a limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I also agree with all of the other reactions; convergence equals having a limit.  Re "A ck-12 calculus book stated they are different concepts.", please edit your query to be more explicit re what the calculus book is saying, perhaps with an example.  This will allow mathSE reviewers to (perhaps) resolve your confusion (e.g. provide reactions pertinent to the example offered by your Calculus book).

Answer (score 0):

*If* a series is convergent *then* it has bounded partial sums. Equivalently, *if* a series fails to have bounded partial sums *then* it is divergent.

*The converse is false*. If a series has bounded partial sums then it need not be convergent. A counter-example is $\sum_{n \ge 1}(-1)^n$ where the partial sums are $-1,0,-1,0,-1,\ldots$.

The partial sums obtain a finite limit *if and only* if the series is convergent.

Comment: Boundedness of partial sums *is* a sufficient condition if the terms are nonnegative, though.

Answer (score 0):

In every calculus and real analysis book I've read, the two are the same thing.For example, in Stewart's calculus:

> 1. A sequence $\{a_n\}$ has the **limit** $L$ and we write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L\quad\text{or}\quad a_n\to L\text{ as }n\to\infty$$ if we can make the terms $a_n$ as close to $L$ as we like by taking $n$ sufficiently large. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ exists, we say the sequence **converges** (or is **convergent**). Otherwise we say the sequence **diverges** (or is **divergent**).
> 2. Given a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$, let $s_n$ denote its $n$th partial sum: $$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$$ If the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is convergent and $lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=s$ exists as a real number, then the series $\Sigma a_n$ is called **convergent** and we write $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n+\cdots=s\quad\text{or}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=s$$ The number $s$ is called the **sum** of the series. If the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is divergent, then the series is called **divergent**.

Either a series converges, or it diverges. Converge means it has a limit. Diverge means it doesn't.